# Show all employees who were hired on the day of the week on which the highest number of employees were hired

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
SELECT last_name, TO_CHAR(hire_date, ’DAY’) day

FROM employees

WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date, ’Day’) =

(SELECT TO_CHAR(hire_date, ’Day’)

FROM employees

GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, ’Day’)

HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))

FROM employees

GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, ’Day’)));
```

The error shows that

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '’'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near '’'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near '’'.

We are using MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Looks like the query above is far too complex than it should be. See if something like (or an equivalent of) the following written for MySQL helps you: `SELECT e1.last_name, e1.hire_date
FROM employees e1
INNER JOIN 
 ( 
  SELECT e2.hire_date, count(e2.hire_date) as hire_date_count 
    FROM employees e2 
   GROUP BY e2.hire_date
   ORDER BY hire_date_count DESC LIMIT 1 
 ) AS t
ON e1.hire_date = t.hire_date`. The date formatting should only be done on the field in the outermost select - no point trying to format dates for each `SELECT` for the specified requirement.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.

Comment: It showed an error that has incorrect syntax near LIMIT

Comment: @Jamal - Which DBMS are you really using? From `TO_CHAR`, it seems you are using Oracle (or something else).

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT last_name,TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY') as day 
FROM employees
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY') IN (SELECT TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY')
                                   FROM employees GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY')
                                   HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) 
                                                      FROM employees
                                                      GROUP BY 
                                                      TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT last_name, TO_CHAR(hire_date, ’DAY’) day    
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date =
(SELECT hire_date
FROM employees
GROUP BY hire_date
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(COUNT(*)))
```

can you try this?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '’'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @JamalMagloire one bracket  is missing can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT last_name,TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY') as Week_Day
FROM employees
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY') 
IN (SELECT T.day
    FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY') as day,COUNT(TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY')) as cnt
          FROM employees GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY'))T
          WHERE T.cnt = (SELECT MAX(T.cnt) 
                         FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY') as 
                                      day,COUNT(TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY')) as cnt
                               FROM employees GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DAY'))T))
```

Comment: I used Inline view to obtain the count of each day in employee table and then used MAX() function to obtain the day on which maximum employees hired. I figured out one more solution simpler than this one. I will use nested Aggregate function. Posting new solution below this .